# Google Map is not working on the second tab of Tab Plugins

Tags: google-maps, tabs

I am using a [postTabs plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posttabs/) and [Comprehensive Google Map Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin/), my problem was when I have my Google map on the second tab, the map is not loading as expected. But if I move it on the 1st tab it works really great.. Is there any way to make the map work on the second tab? Actually, whichever Tab plugin I use the map is not loading properly on the second tab.. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: http://dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/cometostay/bb-directory/england/
you can also try searching from homepage beside the slider and choose England for country and Devon for Region,, or just replace the "england" in url with "wales", "northern-ireland", or "scotland"

Comment: done, Im very sorry, I just don't know how to accept the answer, that was only happened when I'm a starter in this forum. Sorry buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was tested with [Google Maps Embed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-maps-embed/) plugin with PostTabs plugin. You can Insert the map in editor also.This is really works.

Please Check the screenshot for both tabs. :)

[image: Tab 1 here]
[image: Tab 2 here]
Admin Page:
[image: Admin page]

Comment: How did you do that? did you add any customization or you just used the postTabs in default?

Comment: Please Check my Updated answer.post page screenshot was attached. No Customization needed. :)

Comment: You are right, its working.. but why not on the Comprehensive Google Map Plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin/ , have you ever tried it before?

Comment: may be the plugin was not support.

Comment: Ok thanks :), I'll use the Google Maps Embed  for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS if the map shows only one tile or fills in the canvas as a small edge and marker is not centered, when you place it in any other tab than the first.

Easiest solution after hours of searching high and low for a jQuery script to fix this I turned to the css, as none of those scripts worked.

```
.tab-content>.active {position:relative;left:0;display: block;}
.tab-content>.tab-pane{right:-1000px}
```

I had to set the tab pane self to position absolute as it dropped about 100 pixels to the bottom, after first changes.

.tab-pane {position: absolute;margin-left:0px;}

and voila no more gray parts - without additional scripting the map sits centered in the content part of the tab. bootstrap.css hides the panels - which does not work for Google maps.
As I use Pronamic Google maps I additionally had to position the .pgm class .
Piece of cake in retrospective.